# The type or namespace name 'NUnit' could not be found | Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nunit

i have next errors:

```
The type or namespace name 'NUnit' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'UnitySetUpAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'UnitySetUp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'TestAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

More under a page:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEE39.png)

Code: 
https://pastebin.com/5zTjwPZw

How fix it?

Comment: Do you have the [`Test Framework` package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.test-framework@1.0/manual/index.html) imported to your project via the [`PackageManager`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-ui.html)?

Comment: Thanks for answer. No, how tryed - i'll write.

Comment: Hmm, yeah i have. https://imgur.com/a/MigRXLz

Comment: I tryed install UNnit - https://imgur.com/a/lfUCxbb
Command: F:\nunit\nunit3-console.exe F:\heze\bin\net40\nunit.framework.tests.dll
But after this error is not fix.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in a **custom package** after updating to **2020.2.3f1.**

In the case of packages (or if you are using assemblies), they now seem to enforce that Editor's only assemblies should be marked as such in the Platforms section of the inspector:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Test code needs to be under Editor, so it compiles to the Assembly-CSharp-Editor-*.dll which has references to the nunit dlls.

I find this particularly confusing given a quick inspection of Assembly-CSharp-*.csproj will show the nunit.framework listed as a reference, and the fact that it will also build if you point msbuild at the generated solution within vscode (whilst simultaneously failing a Unity 'refresh').